# Unable to create post on my Google plus activity

Tags: curl, google-plus

How to sent `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` values for google plus..add post.

I'm able to get ..authentication token on google plus..but when I add post on google plus.. then I am getting that error

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"forbidden",
            "message":"Forbidden"
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"Forbidden"
   }
}
```

Send data

```
{  
   "object":{  
      "originalContent":"Happy weekend!"
   },
   "access":{  
      "items":[  
         {  
            "type":"domain"
         }
      ],
      "domainRestricted":true
   }
}
```

code:

```
 $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/' . $user_id . '/activities';

    $headers = array(

        'Authorization : Bearer ' . $accesstoken,

        'Content-Type : application/json',

        'Accept : application/json',

    );

  $post_data = array("object" => array("originalContent" => "Happy weekend!"), "access" => array("items" => array(array("type" => "domain")),"domainRestricted" => true));

   //$post_data = array("message" => "Shareing Message to your account will be here");


    ///$post_data['newcontent'] = "Post on Google Plus Test By Me";

    echo $data_string = json_encode($post_data);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $file_result = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r($file_result);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: 403, you don't have permission

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes for this problem:

1. Your question says you are trying to post to [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/).  There is no way to post to Google+ the social media site the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/) is read only.
2. Your code is trying to post to google plus domains.   Using the [Google+ domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/).  That error is caused by the user you are authenticating with not having access to a [google plus domains account](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/).  Double check that the user has the correct access to your Google Plus Domains account.  Also please fix the title and tag of your question to correctly reflect that you are asking about Google Plus domains and not Google plus the social media site.

If you are trying to post to Google+ the social media website you can stop now because its not possible to do that.